# Zend framework form hash not working

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a simple ZF form that includes a hash element:

```
$hash = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('hash');
        $hash->setSalt('hf823hflw03j');
        $hash->addErrorMessage('Form must not be resubmitted');
```

This works ok, but if I choose to strip out all the decorators and format the form using :

```
$this->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_form_register.phtml'))));
```

Then it seems that the hash value is renewed each time it is submitted and thus doesn't work.

In addition, PHPunit thinks the form element hash is invalid and so doesn't test the form processing.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to use viewScript Decorator? Otherwise try to use this:

```
$this->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));
```

If you want to change the look of the Errors, you could create your own ErrorDecorator and then use it as follows:

```
$this->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper', new My_ErrorDecorator()));
```